# Why stl map inserts another value if key already exist, and not just change it?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, duplicate-data

Why does my program using STL maps insert values when keys already exist instead of changing the existing values?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct CTest
{
    int a, b, c;
    CTest(int A, int B, int C) : a(A), b(B), c(C) {}
};

bool operator<(const CTest & l, const CTest & r)
{
    if(l.a < r.a) return true;
    else if(l.a > r.a) return false;

    if(l.b < r.b) return true;
    else if(l.b > r.b) return false;

    if(l.c < r.c) return true;
    else if(l.c > r.c) return false;

    return true;
}

struct CTest2
{
    bool operator<(const CTest2 & r) const
    {
        return q < r.q && w < r.w;
    }
    int q,w;
    CTest2() : q(0), w(0) {}
    CTest2(int Q, int W) : q(Q), w(W) {}
};

int main()
{
    // map of maps
    map<CTest, map<string, CTest2> > x;

    x[CTest(1,1,1)]["lol"] = CTest2(1,2); // x[CTest(1,1,1)]["lol"] now stores CTest2(1,2)
    x[CTest(1,1,1)]["lol"] = CTest2(3,4); // CTest2(1,2) must be changed to CTest2(3,4)
    x[CTest(1,1,1)]["lol"] = CTest2(5,6); // now to CTest2(5,6)

    x[CTest(2,1,0)]["ha"] = CTest2(11,12);

    for(map<CTest, map<string, CTest2> >::iterator i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); ++i)
        for(map<string, CTest2>::iterator j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); ++j)
            cout << j->first << " " << j->second.q << " " << j->second.w << endl;
}
```

Running this prints:

```
lol 3 4
lol 1 2
ha 11 12
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The comparison function which `std::map` uses to sort the elements **must adhere** to [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). But your implementation doesn't do it. As per your implementation, when all members (a, b, c) are **equal**, your `operator<` returns `true`. In other words, `(1,1,1) < (1,1,1)` returns `true`. Does it make sense? No.

An easy fix is this:

```
bool operator<(const CTest & l, const CTest & r)
{
    if(l.a < r.a) return true;
    else if(l.a > r.a) return false;

    if(l.b < r.b) return true;
    else if(l.b > r.b) return false;

    return l.c < r.c;
}
```

That is too verbose. Instead of `<`, if you use `!=`, the above will reduce to this:

```
bool operator<(const CTest & l, const CTest & r)
{
    if(l.a != r.a) return l.a < r.a;
    else if(l.b != r.b) return l.b < r.b;
    return l.c < r.c;
}
```

Well, that is still verbose, you can implement it as:

```
bool operator<(const CTest & l, const CTest & r)
{
   return std::tie(l.a,l.b,l.c) < std::tie(r.a,r.b,r.c);
}
```

The [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) function returns [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) whose [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) implements strick weak ordering, so take advantage of this fact.

Answer (score 8):

Your `operator<()` returns `true` for equal elements.

Answer (score 1):

The code you linked has an error in `operator <`: it returns `true` when keys are equal. It gives a runtime debug assertion at `'x[CTest(1,1,1)]["lol"] = CTest2(3,4);`. If you change `return true;` to `return false;` it will work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Your < operator for CTest is incorrect. You are returning true in cases where l's members are all equal to r's members. If l == r, how is it less than r ? Basically this means the map doesn't see each CTest(1,1,1) as equivalent, so will create a new mapping each time you assign to it.